# Get selected name from select tag

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, jsp, select

```
$scope.states = [ 
{"state_id":1,"state_code":"AN","state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar"},
{"state_id":2,"state_code":"AP","state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},
{"state_id":3,"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh\t"},
{"state_id":4,"state_code":"AS","state_name":"Assam"},
{"state_id":5,"state_code":"BR","state_name":"Bihar"}
];

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select data-ng-model='state' id="state" class="form-control">
            <option value=''>--SELECT--</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat='st in states' value="{{st.state_code}}">{{st.state_name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

By fetching `$scope.state`, i get selected state value i.e, `st.state_code`

But i want to fetch selected name i.e, `st.state_name`.

Using JQuery, i can get it by `$("#state option:selected").text()` but,

How to achieve it using AngularJS?

Comment: Can you put name in value and check?

Comment: Can you please try the answer I have given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var eventsApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
eventsApp.controller('EventController', function($scope){
    $scope.states = [
        {"state_id":1,"state_code":"AN","state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar"},
        {"state_id":2,"state_code":"AP","state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},
        {"state_id":3,"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh\t"},
        {"state_id":4,"state_code":"AS","state_name":"Assam"},
        {"state_id":5,"state_code":"BR","state_name":"Bihar"}
    ];
    $scope.loadDistrict = function(){
        alert($scope.state.state_name);
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select data-ng-model='state' id="state" class="form-control" data-ng-change='loadDistrict()' data-ng-options="state as state.state_name for state in states track by state.state_id">
            <option value=''>--SELECT--</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Look at the above answer. It will give entire object of selected state. $scope.state will have object of selected state and you can access any property of state object.

Comment: why `track by state.state_id`?

Comment: It is optional, not necessary, you can ommit that part too.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, just have a function in the controller and get the **`state`** as a parameter,

**DEMO**

```js
var eventsApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
eventsApp.controller('EventController', function($scope){
$scope.states = [
{"state_id":1,"state_code":"AN","state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar"},
{"state_id":2,"state_code":"AP","state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},
{"state_id":3,"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh\t"},
{"state_id":4,"state_code":"AS","state_name":"Assam"},
{"state_id":5,"state_code":"BR","state_name":"Bihar"}
];
$scope.loadDistrict = function(selectedstate){
  alert(selectedstate);
}
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="EventController">
      <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select data-ng-model='state' id="state" class="form-control" data-ng-change='loadDistrict(state)'>
            <option value=''>--SELECT--</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat='st in states' value="{{st.state_name}}">{{st.state_name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is there any other way, without passing it to function?

Comment: by using `$scope.state` i get value. I dont want selected value,  i want selected name (text)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` like this

`ng-options="item.state_name as item.state_name for item in states"`

Then use `ng-model` variable to access the value

`<label class="control-label col-sm-4">State : {{state}}</label>`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.states = [
{"state_id":1,"state_code":"AN","state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar"},
{"state_id":2,"state_code":"AP","state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},
{"state_id":3,"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh\t"},
{"state_id":4,"state_code":"AS","state_name":"Assam"},
{"state_id":5,"state_code":"BR","state_name":"Bihar"}
];

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State : {{state}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select data-ng-model='state' id="state" class="form-control" data-ng-change='loadDistrict(state)' ng-options="item.state_name as item.state_name for item in states">
            <option value=''>--SELECT--</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any other way, without passing it to function?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `value = {{st.state_code}}`, you will have `ng-model` of the `select` as id value. If you change it to `value = {{st.state_name}}`, you will get name as your selected value.

As your requirement, you can use jQLite to achieve this as:

`angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.form-control option:checked')).text();`

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8eoIKsxirPrIM1lHERKm?p=preview)

Hope this helps.

Comment: offcourse it can be done, but im looking an answer for my question

Comment: You mean, you want to get text content of selected option?

Comment: Updated answer. Once check it.

Answer (score 1):

In value you put state_name, then you will get name in state

```
<option data-ng-repeat='st in states' value="{{st.state_name}}">{{st.state_name}}</option>
```

Comment: offcourse it can be done, but im looking an answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

just change the value of options to $state.name from $state.code

```
    $scope.states = [ 
{"state_id":1,"state_code":"AN","state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar"},
{"state_id":2,"state_code":"AP","state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},
{"state_id":3,"state_code":"AR","state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh\t"},
{"state_id":4,"state_code":"AS","state_name":"Assam"},
{"state_id":5,"state_code":"BR","state_name":"Bihar"}
];

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">State :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select data-ng-model='state' id="state" class="form-control">
            <option value=''>--SELECT--</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat='st in states' value="{{st.state_name}}">{{st.state_name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This shall do the job.